# Ubuntu 20.04 - CD Drive keeps opening/closing randomly

Tags: cd-drive

***Ubuntu 20.04***

I have tried below solutions provided in Ubuntu forums but it has not solved the problem.

**eject -v -a off**  - Tried this but did not solve the problem
**sudo setcd -s /dev/sr0**  - This solution id for Dell PC but nevertheless tried. Did not work

Comment: Could you add the full output of `sudo eject -v -a off` to your question?

Comment: govind@Saras:~$ sudo eject -v -a off
eject: using default device `cdrom'
eject: device name is `cdrom'
eject: expanded name is `/dev/cdrom'
eject: `/dev/cdrom' is a link to `/dev/sr0'
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not mounted
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not a mount point
eject: disabling auto-eject mode for `/dev/sr0'
govind@Saras:~$

Comment: Looks like the only way is pull off power cable to CD Drive to stop opening randomly. But then, I will not be able to use CD Drive when needed.

Comment: You should rule out hardware malfunction. Turn on the computer but don't let it boot into Linux, you can go to the setup menu, or the boot menu and then do nothing. If the drive opens up by itself after a while, or even at boot, then Linux is not the problem.

Comment: Similar issue discussed below. https://superuser.com/questions/1343049/dvd-drive-opening-automatically

Comment: Anyone else suffering this should also tick "this bug also affects me" on Launchpad, here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1942299

Answer (score -1):

As indicated in the comments, this problem is probably the same as https://superuser.com/questions/1343049/dvd-drive-opening-automatically

My alternative solution to avoid changing systemd is by simply inserting a '0' into /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoeject

Pick one:

Using rc.local:  ( edit file /etc/rc.local )

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoeject
```

Or using /etc/crontab:  ( edit file /etc/crontab )

```
@reboot root    echo 0 > /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoeject
```

Then as a one-time, non-persistant across boots, command line use sudo:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoeject
```

Which will take effect immediately. No sysctl or service file restart. needed...  On the next boot, the modifications to rc.local or /etc/crontab.
will take effect, inhibiting the AutoOpen function.

Comment: You do seem to have nailed the problem, but sadly this fix has no effect on Ubuntu 22.04.